# How to assign different class name on view element

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my Backbone view, i am setting tagname, classname, temp value.. all are works fine apart from classname..

how do i set the classname.. or what is the mistake on my code..

```
define(["singleton","listCollection","listModel"],function(singleton,collection,listModel){
    singleton.view = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName     :'article',
        className   :'indBoard',
        projectName : true,
        template0   : _.template($('#listTemplate').html()),
        template1   : _.template($('#boardTemplate').html()),
        initialize  :function(options){
            this.template = this['template'+options.tempNo];
            this.tagName = options.tagName;
                    //i am changing to 'li' works
            this.className = options.cName; 
                    //changing to new class name not working
            console.log(options.cName);//consoles new class name properly
                  this.projectName = options.subTempNo == 0 ?true:false;                 
                   //condition as well works..
        },
        render:function(){
            var temp = this.template;
            this.$el.html(temp(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
    return singleton.view;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `options.className` when you create your view instance instead of `options.cName`, you don't need to try to set it in `initialize` like that (same for tagName).

Try something like this instead:

`var view = new singleton.view({className: 'someClass'});`

`className` is one of the special options that Backbone looks for during the view creation.

From [Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js):

```
// List of view options to be merged as properties.
var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'];
```

Actually, I think the reason `tagName` is working for you is because it is being merged in by Backbone, and not because you are setting it in `initialize`.

Comment: Yes, your are 100% correct. works find according to your advice.